# Ability to edit Word documents with a .NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, office365

I've been asked to give users the ability to upload existing Word documents or to create a new Word document within our application as part of editing a mailing template.  The editing should occur within a frame as it would be part of a large page.

Are there third-party components for the import and UI or even better does Office 365 allow this type of functionality?

Comment: I just been wondering how Outlook does this: outlook can configure Microsoft Word as default editor for emails. It's obvious then that microsoft word can be tamed to be used as rich editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end solution, which is robust, secure and high performance was to use IT Hit WebDAV Server for .NET.

https://www.webdavsystem.com

Comment: Hi, I'm curious how exactly you implemented this, i had a look at the demos and looks very promising but have no idea how to begin with the actual implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Office Online** to integrate view/editing of office documents. For more information see [Integrating with Office Online](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).